# Problems with linking lua statically

Tags: linker, lua, static-libraries

I'm trying to link lua statically into my C++ application with VS2012. I downloaded the vs11_lib files off of sourceforge and added linker dependencies for this file, lua52.lib. I'm now getting all sorts of link errors when I try to compile and I'm pretty sure I missed a step. Again, I'm doing this statically since I'd like my application to run stand-alone. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to build embeddable Lua yourself. Download source files for your desired version, create a static library project in VS2012, copy the source files (*.h and *.c to the VS project, not VS solution) and add all source files to the project, except `luac.c` and `lua.c`, which are needed for standalone executable rather than embedded library (and they conflict with each other in one project anyway).

After that compile the release version and you got yourself lua5.x.lib that you can link against. If it's still not working, then the problem might be that you added linker dependencies in the wrong place.

Comment: If you're using Lua 5.1, also leave out `print.c`.

Comment: But this should be the same thing available from lua binaries correct?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, because it should work, no, because performance may be different. I've actually performed a little test, 200 million iterations of just create / destroy a table. The downloaded version did it in 21 seconds, the one compiled in vs did it in 19 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Lua sources can be compiled as C or C++. I figure the lib files you are trying to use are compiled as C and you are including their headers as C++. The outcome would be that the names of the functions are different; ergo, the linking errors.

If you are using a C lib in a C++ file, wrap the lib's header like so:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"
}
```

For more detailed instructions using Lua with Visual Studio, see this [article](http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-lua/).

UPDATE:

As, @lhf says in a comment, the newer distributions of Lua provide a C++ header `lua.hpp` which does the same thing. It is described for older distributions in [PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.1.html).

Comment: Use `lua.hpp`=, which comes with the source distribution.

Comment: Right, I am certainly doing this. The only binary I am using is lua5.1.lib. I should add that the file size is rather small, 640kb. Is  there some other binary I should be using?

Comment: No, Lua is quite small. That seems to be the 64-bit library. So you need to the 32-bit library? What are the errors you see?

Comment: @ChristopherBrown you've most likely linked to the 64-bit version, as Tom Blodget pointed out.

Comment: Weird! it worked with the 32! I'm running a 64 bit system though, any reason I can't use the 64 bit version?